# How to edit a review item for a tag wiki excerpt?

Tags: support, feature-request

i've just taken a look at a review item for a tag wiki excerpt.  the text is mostly okay, but could use a little polishing.  however, there's no option to edit -- only "approve", "reject" or "skip".  i know i can improve the text (it doesn't need much), but can't figure out how.

(i was initially unable to post this because "it doesn't meet our quality standards".  not until i uppercased a lot of things i wouldn't ordinarily, was it accepted.  fie.)

Comment: related unanswered [question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2469/15717)

Comment: So you saw an "Approve", "Reject" and "Skip" option, but no "Improve"?

Comment: @Werner -- yes, those were the options.  i have since been informed that i don't yet have enough reputation to "final edit" tag wiki excerpts, and that's okay.  the one i was looking at has since been approved, i've edited what was posted, and it was pended for approval for those with that privilege.  (i don't expect my edit to be rejected, but i certainly don't mind it being checked.)  so maybe the (lack of) reputation had something to do with the options offered; that's plausible, but confusing.

Comment: @tohecz -- thank you for humoring me.  have a very happy new year.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I hope I haven't done anything wrong. Have a nice time, too! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be related to your reputation at the time. It's difficult to fully assess this since it's only noticeable when there's a wiki tag edit to review (which doesn't happen often *and* it depends on the individual reviewing it).

My assumption is based on falling within the 5,000 to 20,000 reputation category. The former (under)bound allows users to [Approve or reject tag wiki edits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), while the latter bound designates a so-called [Trusted user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) allowing them to "Approve", "Reject" or "Improve" (or "Skip") the review:

[image]

As mentioned, it's difficult to confirm this, since reputation at this level is mostly a one-way road.

Comment: i've tried to recall the exact circumstances, and i think i was linked into a non-tex.sx group at the time, noticed the flag, so i accessed it from there.  the reputation in the other group was definitely below 5,000, so this makes sense.  thanks for the review of the possibilities.